# proper way to use nested variables in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In my terraform script, I have

```
resource "azuread_application" "main" {
  count           = "${length(var.sp_names)}"
  name            = "${sp_prefix}-${var.sp_names[count.index]}"

  available_to_other_tenants = false
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "main" {
  count           = "${length(var.sp_names)}"
  application_id  = "${azuread_application.main.["${sp_prefix}"-"${var.sp_names[count.index]}"].application_id}"
}
```

when I ran `terraform init` I get the following error:

> An attribute name is required after a dot.

what is the right way to use nested variables and a list object?

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using? The below answer is related to 0.12.x. I am assuming you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a resource to be represented as a map of instances rather than a list of instances, you need to use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) instead of [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count):

```
resource "azuread_application" "main" {
  for_each = { for n in var.sp_names : n => "${var.sp_prefix}-${n}" }

  name                       = each.value
  available_to_other_tenants = false
}
```

The `for_each` expression above is a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) that transforms your list or set of names into a mapping from the given names to the prefixed names. In the other expressions in that block, `each.key` would therefore produce the original given name and `each.value` the prefixed name.

You can then similarly use `for_each` to declare the intent "create one service principal per application" by using the application resource's map itself as the `for_each` expression for the service principal resource:

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "main" {
  for_each = azuread_application.main

  application_id  = each.value.application_id
}
```

In this case, the `azuread_application.main` value is a map from unprefixed names to objects representing each of the declared applications. Therefore `each.key` in *this* block is the unprefixed name again, but `each.value` is the corresponding application object from which we can access the `application_id` value.

If your `var.sp_names` had a string `"example"` in it, then Terraform would interpret the above as a request to create two objects named `azuread_application.main["example"]` and `azuread_service_principal.main["example"]`, identifying these instances by the `var.sp_names` values. This is different to `count` where the instances would have addresses like `azuread_application.main[0]` and `azuread_service_principal.main[0]`. By using `for_each`, we ensure that adding and removing items from `var.sp_names` will add and remove corresponding instances from those resources, rather than updating existing ones that happen to share the same numeric indices.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using a version older that 0.12.x. If not the answer from Martin is the best one.

You need to leverage the splatting.

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "main" {
  count           = "${length(var.sp_names)}"
  application_id  = "${azuread_application.main.*.application_id}"
}
```